# How can I avoid an “out of index” error with 2D arrays in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, indexing, range

The task is to iterate over all elements within a two-dimensional list and do some specific calculations on each element and its nearest neighbors:

```py
count = 0
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    for j in range(0,len(arr)):
        if arr[i][j] == 7 and is_perfect_cube(arr[i-1][j] + arr[i+1][j] + arr[i][j-1] + arr[i][j+1]):
            count += 1
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting an *index out of range* error. Basing on what I’ve managed to debug so far is that the error occurs for the first and last elements of the collection. I know I could use `float[int]`, but I’m not sure how to apply it to my particular implementation. I couldn’t find any similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code explicitly tries to use elements that are out of array bounds. In this call,

```
is_perfect_cube(arr[i-1][j]+arr[i+1][j]+arr[i][j-1]+arr[i][j+1])
```

you are asking for `arr[i-1][j]` which equals to `-1` for `i=0` - and fetches the last row - this may be desirable in some cases. Then you also ask for `arr[i+1][j]` which for `i` equal to the last element, i.e. `len(arr)-1` is clearly out of bounds and causes an error. The same holds for `arr[i][j+1]` - just in terms of columns and not rows.

To handle this, you need to either ignore the end points (loop from 1 to size-2 in both dimensions) or modify your algorithm for the end points. The choice depends on the problem you are trying to solve. All established algorithms consider end points, you can check what are the solutions for yours.

Comment: Thank you @atru i am aware of arr[i-1] or arr[i+1] situations. I need to check all elements of array. For that i can't use range(1, len(arr)-1). I am stuck how to improve my algorithms for end points.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do, but we need more details on the approach used in perfect cube, best - the whole function if it's not too large (I imagine it's not). End points don't have all their neighbors - unless it is a periodic system. You need to think what to do with them so that your solution is meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    for j in range(0,len(arr)):
        if arr[i][j] == 7:
            try:
                up = arr[i-1][j]
            except:
                up = 0
            try:
                down = arr[i+1][j]
            except:
                down = 0
            try:
                left = arr[i][j-1]
            except:
                left = 0
            try:
                right = arr[i][j+1]
            except:
                right = 0
            if is_perfect_cube(up+down+left+right):
                count += 1
```

This is my solutions for my question. I don't know if this is the correct way to solve out of boundary problems. I am still open for advice

Comment: If this is what you want then I can give you a solution without the try block. Also, I don't know if it's conceptually correct, would need more background on what you're trying to do.